# Python tkinter GUI app still freezes with threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm writing an app (Python 3.x + tkinter).
The problem I had, was that the GUI freezes when the button is pressed.
Which was expected, since the GUI is waiting for the results of several functions, before it can update.
So, I introduces Threading in my app. However, this still freezes the application. The reason is that I have to wait until the thread has finished (thread.join()), so I can again have the results to update the GUI.
I'll post the relevant code snippets here

```
Class CDSapp(tk.Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('CDS')
        
        # ------------- BASIC CDS APP Layout -----------

        self.geometry('800x900')
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.title('CDS')

        menubar=CDSmenu(self)
        
#rest of building the GUI goes here...

        self.runButton=tk.Button(self,text='Run Tests',command=lambda: self.runTests())
        self.runButton.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=20,pady=20,sticky=tk.W)
### updating the labels in notebook
    def runTests(self):
        
        self.testObject=testClass
        
        self.value1=ReturnValueThread(target=self.testObject.Test1,args=([self.generalInformation[3],self.connectionInformation[0]],))
        self.value2=ReturnValueThread(target=self.testObject.Test2,args=())
        self.value3=ReturnValueThread(target=self.testObject.Test3,args=())
        
        self.value1.start()
        self.value2.start()
        self.value3.start()
        
# using join, while I need the results to go to x.x.updateAnswers(a,b)
        self.value1.join()
        self.detailedInfo.updateAnswers(self.value1.result,0)
        self.value2.join()
        self.detailedInfo.updateAnswers(self.value2.result,1)
        self.value3.join()
        self.detailedInfo.updateAnswers(self.value3.result,2)
```

the testClass is a class having several fideunctions. Each function returns a list with values which are used to update labels on the GUI.

I fully understand that the GUI freezes, since the self.valuex.join is in the main function. But I can't figure out how to move it out of the main, since I need the main object to iterate through all the labels....
The "ReturnValueThread" is basically a Thread class extended with a return value...

If more code is needed, I'm happy to provide it. But the issue is clear I believe...
thank you in advance!

Comment: Run `runTests()` in a thread as well.

Comment: How would that look like? while 'runtests()' is a class function of the main window...?

Comment: Or replace `self.value1.join()` by `while self.value1.is_alive(): self.update()`.  Same for `self.value2.join()` and `self.value3.join()`.

Comment: But using the while self.value1.is_alive(): self.update will cause the update function to update the labels while the thread is still running....or?

Comment: using the .is_alive() in a new funtion/method of the main class did the trick!

Comment: The trick will now be to put the threads in a loop, so I can start and monitor multiple threads with limited lines of code instead of repeating the .start() and .monitor(x) for each call....

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, instead of using the "thread.join()" method, I created a 'monitor' function, which uses the .is_alive() method.

It looks like:

```
### mainAPP

...

        self.Value1.start()
        self.Value2.start()
        self.Value3.start()
        self.monitor(self.Value1,0)
        self.monitor(self.Value2,1)
        self.monitor(self.Value3,2)
      
    def monitor(self, myThread,myFrame):
        """ Monitor the download thread """
        if myThread.is_alive():
            self.after(100, lambda: self.monitor(myThread,myFrame))
        else:
            self.detailedInfo.updateAnswers(myThread.result,myFrame)
```

The results are now updated async and the windows does not freeze anymore!

Thank you all for taking the time to help me out!